# Error in my DBSCAN algorithm. Matlab version

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, dbscan

Currently I'm using DBSCAN algorithm to cluster my data, but I got some problem here. As you know DBSCAN needs 3 parameter before start. First is epsilon which is the search range of a core point. Second, is the MinPts or you can say the minimum number of points to form a cluster. Third is the dataset.

DBSCAN start the work by jump into a random point. This point can be called as a core point candidate. We evaluate with the epsilon, if there are Minpts-1 Points within the epsilon radius. We got exact `MinPts` point inside this epsilon. So we can form a cluster. Then we'll call `expandcluster` function to expand the cluster, all the points within the radius of the epsilon will do their search again with epsilon radius, so the cluster will get bigger. This step stops until the cluster cannot be expanded. We will go to another point which is not assigned in a cluster. If the point has less than `MinPts` point inside the radius, we will flag this point as a noise and continue apoint a point and find new cluster.

I'm using the [dbscan clustering algorithm](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52905-dbscan-clustering-algorithm)

The problem is I have a set of data and i set MinPts 4, Eps 65.5. I got 3 cluster but 1 of the cluster only had 3 points. If we look at the theory it should not happened.

Thank you for coming to this question and I hope I can find the answer...

Answer (score 0):

DBSCAN *can* produce clusters smaller than minPts.

This is a well-known fact, albeit exceptions are rather rare.

> DBSCAN Revisited,
>   Revisited: Why and How You Should (Still) Use DBSCAN. ACM Trans. Database Syst. 42, 3, Article 19 (July
>   2017), 21 pages.
>   https://doi.org/10.1145/3068335

Footnote 1 says:

> [unique labels for border points] can, in rare cases, lead to a cluster with fewer than minPts points, if too many border points are reachable
>   by different clusters, and have previously been assigned to other clusters.

A cluster has at least 1 core point. That is actually guaranteed.

Nevertheless it probably is a good idea if you double check the random-code-you-downloaded-from-the-internet against one of the more widely known implementations out there.

Comment: do you have any papers that reffers to this statement 'DBSCAN can produce clusters smaller than minPts.' ? I understand from the view of border points that it is possible, but the original paper doesnt state anything about this issue.

Comment: DBSCAN revisited revisited, almost same authors. Was in Wikipedia.